# What version of Linux is my server running?

Tags: linux, gnu

So, I have a linux hosting plan with Godaddy. As I was trying to install some packages, the ususal apt-get/aptitude/npm/yum failed. The data I got from uname -a:

```
Linux xxxxxxxxxxxx.zzzz.yyyy.secureserver.net 2.6.32-673.8.1.lve1.4.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 10 08:57:30 EST 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Could someone please help me identify what this is running?

Comment: `cat /etc/*ease` should tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

`cat /etc/*-release`

or

`lsb_release -a`.

[Reference](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-linux-distribution-name-version-number/).